# How to measure execution time of thread in macos?

Tags: c++, c, objective-c, multithreading, macos

Is there any way to measure execution time of thread under macos? I know that there is `getrusage` function, but it is supposed only to measure process time (Under linux there is extension to measure thread time, but unfortunately I work under MacOs). I need to measure time of thread (the sum of processed time in user and kernel spaces). The exact analogue is `GetThreadTimes` under `Windows` (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-getthreadtimes)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can pass `RUSAGE_THREAD` for the first parameter to `getrusage`.

Edit:
Looks like Mac supports only `RUSAGE_SELF` and `RUSAGE_CHILDREN`.

`CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID` is another option, which tracks CPU time for a calling thread. Note that this is CPU time and not wall clock time, i.e for example any time spent sleeping won't be accounted for.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <time.h>

void* thread_func(void* args)
{
        struct timespec tp;
        ret = clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &tp);
        printf("thread elapsed secs: %ld nsecs %ld\n", tp.tv_sec, tp.tv_nsec);
}
int main()
{
        pthread_t thread;
        pthread_create(&thread, NULL, thread_func, NULL);
        pthread_join(thread, NULL);
}
```

Comment: As I understood it is linux extension (not macos), where I can find defintion of this macro under macos? Can you give working example please?

Comment: Ah you're right. Looks like mac supports only RUSAGE_SELF or RUSAGE_CHILDREN.
You can try clock_gettime(CLOCK_THREAD_CPUTIME_ID, &tp).

Comment: I accepted answer. But documentation does not mention about cpu time. Is it time spent by thread in user and kernel spaces?

Comment: Yes its the accumulated time the thread was running on a CPU, both in kernel and userland.